# Check Non Optional value for nil

Tags: swift, exception, optional-variables, optional-binding

I'm creating a function in swift to check the if non optional value return nil. My aim is just to handle that exception and avoid app crash for unexpected nil values.

I have two variables in my class:

```
// My Class variables
var compulsoryValue: Any!
```

I dont want to check `optionalValue` as nil. The compiler is returning `Optional.none` or `Optional.some` enums instead of `nil` or some value.

**My problem:**

I'm facing the problem that I am not able to check if this value is empty or not. As for empty the compiler returning `none` while for a `value` it is return some as defined in `Swift` `Optional Enum`.
`Implicitly Unwrapped Optional` is just throwing an error while it has a `nil` value.

How I can check that the value nil which was supposed as a non-optional value?

**Update# 1:**

My code:

```
class myClass {

    var compulsoryValue: Any!

    init() {

          if type(of: compulsoryValue) != Optional<Any>.self {
                // Here I want to check if compulsoryValue is nil so I want to throw an exception
                print("this is not optional: ", compulsoryValue)
            }
    }
}

_ = myClass()
```

Comment: Show your actual code that you need help with.

Comment: Please check my code, I want to throw an exception when it will be nil which was supposed as non-optional value.

Comment: Why do you need this? Any attempt to use an implicitly unwrapped variable when it is still nil will result in an exception automatically. No need to write convoluted code to check yourself.

Comment: It is not showing `nil` it is showing `none` and the app crash just because of this.

Comment: If you want to check, use `if compulsoryValue == nil { // it's nil, do something }`.

Comment: If its `nil` somewhere then you should make it `Optional`.

Comment: I am not able to check like this, compliler considers it as non optional values and warns that this will always return false.

Comment: It would be better if you can share your actual code.

Comment: @Kamran this is actual code, I am writhing a function in a class and this will be use where needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass {

    var compulsoryValue: Any!
    var optionalValue: Any?

    init() {

        let variabless = [compulsoryValue, optionalValue]



        for (_, v) in variabless.enumerated() {

            if(v != nil) { //Or v == nil
                 // Here I want to check if v is nil so I want to throw an exception
                print("this is not optional: ", v)
            }
        }    
    }
}

_ = myClass()
```

Comment: Please do not confuse with the optional value, I want to check the `var compulsoryValue: Any!` only and that would not be checked by nil check.

Comment: @developer how `compulsoryValue` will not be checked by `nil`? Declaring a variable `non-optional` just tells the compiler to believe you will always provide some value. But it has nothing to do checking for nil or value.

Comment: yes but through some sense, it can be set as nil and compiler will set as nil. I want to check.

Comment: Yes, this is what the above code in answer is doing. It will tell you if your non-optional variable is nil or not.